# how to easily select an indicator from a long list of PopupMenu within Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate, popup

The following `code` (from this forum) works as expected, allowing a quick selection of an indicator from a very long list of `PopupMenu`:

```
ClearAll[searchPopup, selection];
searchPopup[Dynamic[selection_], list_List] := 
DynamicModule[{x = ""}, 
Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[x], String, Appearance -> "Frameless", 
   ContinuousAction -> True, FieldHint -> "Search", 
   FieldSize -> 10], Spacer[5], 
  Dynamic[PopupMenu[Dynamic[selection, (selection = #; x = #) &], 
    Cases[list, 
     z_String /; StringMatchQ[z, x ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True]], 
    Null, Opener[True, Appearance -> Small]], 
   TrackedSymbols :> {x}]}}, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Center},
 Background -> White, Frame -> True, 
FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]]];
selection = "";
searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], indicatorList]
```

I tried to integrate this `code` into the `Manipulate[...]` given below:

```
  ClearAll[categoryList];
categoryList = {"status", "subregion", "country"};

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  ds[GroupBy[Key[categoryList[[category]]]], All, {var1, var2}],
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  PlotLabel -> {var1  ,   var2},
  FrameLabel -> {var1, var2},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  AspectRatio -> 1/1.62
  ],
 {{category, 1, "categories"}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[categoryList]] -> categoryList], 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {{var1, indicatorList[[1]], "X-axis"}, indicatorList, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {{var2, indicatorList[[2]], "Log[Y-axis]"}, indicatorList, 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 ]
```

My question is how to integrate:

```
searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], indicatorList]
```

into the above `Manipulate`. I have already made a few attempts but did not work. The list of `indicatorList` is ready and a very long one. Data is not relevant to the question. I like to receive guidance for the integration concerned.

**EDIT**
Here it is a short list of `indicatorList`:

```
indicatorList= {"Population", "Poverty headcount", "GNI, Atlas     
method", "GNI per capita", "GNI (current $)", "GNI per capita",
"Income share held by lowest 20%", "Life expectancy at birth",
"Fertility rate", "Adolescent fertility rate", "Contraceptive 
prevalence", "Births attended by skilled staff", "Mortality  
rate, under-5", "Prevalence of underweight", "Immunization", 
"Primary completion rate", "School enrollment", "School 
enrollment, primary", "Prevalence of HIV", "Forest area", "Water 
productivity", "Energy use", "CO2 emissions", "Adolescents", 
"Adolescents (age 15 years)", "Environmental performance index", 
"INFORM risk index"};
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is a revised `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
{var1, var2},
{{var1, indicatorList[[1]], "X-axis"}, indicatorList, 
ControlType -> PopupMenu},
{{var2, indicatorList[[2]], "Log[Y-axis]"}, indicatorList, 
ControlType -> PopupMenu}
]
```

Comment: Please give a small example of "indicatorList"

Comment: @Daniel Huber: In a few minutes, I will edit the question with a small list.

Comment: I am sorry, but there is still a problem, "ds" is not defined.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: My purpose was not really to make `ListPlot`s but only to know how to integrate two pieces of `codes`. I will remove `ListPlot` from the existing`Manipulate` and give a revised workable `Manipulate`.

Comment: @Daniel Huber: I revised the `Manipulate`.

Comment: @Daniel huber: I tried: `Manipulate[
 {var1, var2},
 {var1, searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], indicatorList]},
 {var2, searchPopup[Dynamic[selection], indicatorList]}
 ]`. Is this the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Manipulate[{var1, var2}, 
 {{var1, indicatorList[[1]], "X-axis"}, searchPopup[#, indicatorList] &}, 
 {{var2, indicatorList[[2]], "Log[Y-axis]"}, searchPopup[#, indicatorList] &}]
```

[image]

Comment: One of my papers has been accepted for publication by the `Journal of Economic Structures` (forthcoming early next year). There I acknowledged your `code`  and provided the `https` link to the MMA. Thank you again for your utmost help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to incorporate a popup menu in a manipulate. This can be easily accomplished with built in functions without additional code.

Here is a simple example:

```
list = {"item1", "item2", "item3"};
Manipulate[
 "My choice is: " <> choice, {{choice, "item1", "Item: "}, 
  PopupMenu[#, list] &}]
```

[image]